# Get a vector which contains the string before one specific character from each element in a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

`df = data.frame(V1= c(1:3), V2 = c("abc-1-10", "def-2-19", "ghi-3-937"))`

I would like to be able to add a column V3 to this dataframe such that the column V3 contains the string before the first hyphen ("-") in column V2. So it should look like this:

`dfDesired = data.frame(V1= c(1:3), V2 = c("abc-1-10", "def-2-19", "ghi-3-937"), V3 = c("abc", "def","ghi"))`

When I try using strsplit, it gives me a list of vectors with the three parts of the each string.

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex friendly way is using `tidyr::separate`:

```r
tidyr::separate(df, V2, into = "V3", extra = "drop", remove = F, sep = "-")

  V1        V2  V3
1  1  abc-1-10 abc
2  2  def-2-19 def
3  3 ghi-3-937 ghi
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, if the string before the first hyphen has underscores (mine do), it does not work as it also removes everything after the underscore

Comment: See edit. You can modify the sep argument.

Comment: Lovely! This solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can drop everything after the first `-`

In base R,

```
transform(df, V3 = sub('-.*', '', V2))

#  V1        V2  V3
#1  1  abc-1-10 abc
#2  2  def-2-19 def
#3  3 ghi-3-937 ghi
```

Comment: Also a great solution if one is comfortable using regex.